# How else can I troubleshoot this cron job?

Tags: python, cron, freebsd

I've been working (and searching) to get this cron job / python script running for some time now.  However, it's obviously not working.  I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot why, and I've tried several things I've found here in other SO questions.

path to script:  /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus.py

I would like cron to run every minute.

Crontab.txt file:

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py &> octolog.txt
```

The octolog.txt was to capture the STDOUT and STDERR info.  Output of "sudo tail /var/log/cron"

```
Jul  3 10:20:00 bsd /usr/sbin/cron[83876]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Jul  3 10:20:00 bsd /usr/sbin/cron[83877]: (phil) CMD (python /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py &> octolog.txt)
Jul  3 10:21:00 bsd /usr/sbin/cron[83903]: (phil) CMD (python /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py &> octolog.txt)
Jul  3 10:22:00 bsd /usr/sbin/cron[83934]: (phil) CMD (python /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py &> octolog.txt)
```

It appears to be running each minute as desired.  However, the expected results of the script are not occurring.  octolog.txt is also not being created.  When I manually run the exact statement shown in the cron-log, everything works correctly as expected, and the octolog.txt file is created.

I am running this on FreeBSD, and I went to look at the /var/log/syslog, but it doesn't exist.  I'm new to FreeBSD, but I'm not sure that means a lot in this situation, but I thought I'd mention it.

I'm not sure what other info would be helpful, as I'm stuck.  Thanks.  Phil

Comment: not sure: but does cron have a PATH set? meaning: shouldn't you use the absolute path to the python interpreter?

Comment: Have you set your shell for crontab to be /bin/bash. `&>` is not in older bash versions and probably not  in the shell normally used by cron (`/bin/sh`)

Comment: I think you may be on to something.  I created a new directory elsewhere in the structure, and ran the script using absolute paths.  The octolog was created in the PWD, and the errors captured had to do with not being able to locate the mentioned files within the script itself.  I thought, for some reason, that the working directory was the directory of the script itself.  Not sure why I thought that.  Does that mean all files within the script require absolute paths?  I guess I could create a WORKING_DIR variable and append all files to the end of that variable.  Is that the common procedure?

Comment: @Anthon - No, I didn't know I needed to do that.  My user account is using a bash shell.  Is it unadvisable to change the crontab shell?  I would imagine so.

Comment: @pedwards read through `man 5 crontab` you can explicitly set the shell using `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your crontab file.

Comment: I recommend sticking with the default shell for cron, and not changing it this way. If for some reason one of bash's dependencies gets updated such that bash won't run anymore, not only will you not be able to log in, but your cron jobs won't run!  I always leave `tcsh` as my login shell, and run `bash` when I need it. While tcsh is still dynamically linked, it's part of the base system, so it's less likely to get hosed during package updates. I've included some other options in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, to run your script every minute, you don't need `*/1`.  Cron runs every minute by default, so:

```
* * * * * /path/to/command
```

Next, your redirection may be broken.  The `bash` man page has the `&>` format listed under "Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error", so I assume that's what you're trying to do.  But FreeBSD's `/bin/sh` *is not bash*.  So:

```
* * * * * /path/to/command >/path/to/output.txt 2>&1
```

This sends stdout to your file, and duplicates stderr to stdout.

This brings us to:

```
* * * * * python /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py > octolog.txt 2>&1
```

Note also according to `man 5 crontab`, you can set a `MAILTO` variable in your crontab file which will direct output/errors from your jobs to an email address.

Beware that the PATH used by `cron` may not include `/usr/local/bin`, where python is installed.  If your `octoStatus.py` script includes a "shebang", then you may be able to execute it directly.  Otherwise, you will either have to provide the full path to your `python` binary, or add a PATH variable to your crontab (akin to the MAILTO I mentioned above).  In all cases, you can get instructions as to format by reading `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: Thanks.  Although I haven't solved all my issues, this definitely advanced me forward again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you directly write to file from your python script with `append` mode.

Also just guessing but I think you should give absolute path to output  file as stated in comment something like `python home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octoStatus.py &> /home/phil/cron_jobs/octoStatus/octolog.txt`

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer, combined with hiro's comment, helped move me forward in troubleshooting.